# JCascalog/Pail shredding stage works locall,y but not in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cascalog, lambda-architecture

Following the ["Big Data" Lambda Architecture book](http://manning.com/marz/), I've got an incoming directory full of typed Thift Data objects, with a DataPailStructure defined pail.meta file

I take a snapshot of this data:

```
Pail snapshotPail = newDataPail.snapshot(PailFactory.snapshot);
```

The incoming files and meta data files are duplicated, and the pail.meta file also has

```
structure: DataPailStructure
```

Now I want to shred this data, to split it into vertical partitions. As from the book, I create two PailTap objects, one for the Snapshot and the SplitDataStructure, one for the new *Shredded* folder.

```
PailTap source = dataTap(PailFactory.snapshot);
PailTap sink = splitDataTap(PailFactory.shredded);
```

The */Shredded* folder has a pail.meta file with `structure: SplitDataPailStructure`

Following the instructions, I execute the JCascalog query to force the reducer:

```
Api.execute(sink, new Subquery(data).predicate(reduced, empty, data));
```

Now, in local mode, this works fine. There's a "temporary" subfolder created under /Shredded, and this is vertically partitioned with the expected "1/1" structure. In local mode, this then is moved up to the /Shredded folder, and I can consolidate and merge to master without problems.

But running inside Hadoop, it fails at this point, with an error:

```
cascading.tuple.TupleException: unable to sink into output identifier: /tmp/swa/shredded 
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 1/1/part-000000 is not valid with the pail structure {structure=com.hibu.pail.SplitDataPailStructure, args={}, format=SequenceFile} --> [1, _temporary, attempt_1393854491571_12900_r_000000_1, 1, 1] at com.backtype.hadoop.pail.Pail.checkValidStructure(Pail.java:563)
```

Needless to say, if I change the Shredded Sink structure type to DataPailStructure, then it works fine, but it's a fairly pointless operation, as everything is as it was in the Incoming folder. It's okay for now, as I'm only working with one data type, but this is going to change soon and I'll need that partition.

Any ideas? I didn't want to post all my source code here initially, but I'm almost certainly missing something.

Comment: if anyone else runs into this, it's something to do with the isValidTarget method on your PailStructure<T> method - for some reason, "1/1/part-000000" is being passed as the Target, not "1/1" where "part-000000"  is the data file